# Windows Console Based Game

Tags: c++, windows, console

So, I am making a game, and I need input function  to have deadline, and I want that time to be displayed in one of the console corners.
I have timer running on separate thread.
**I want to show user how much time he has left, lets say to write varibale TimeLeft on end of the first line,but keep all other lines intact.**
So is there any function that allows me to print/display/cout variable on specific place inside console window.
Working in C++, Windows platform, console app

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092262/resetting-or-clearing-line-in-c-output/36092727#36092727)

Comment: Duplicate of your previous (closed) question.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use SetConsoleCursorPosition() to set the position in the console, where your output from print/cout will be written. You need to pass the console handle and a COORD structure to the function. You can get the handle with GetStdHandle().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Here's a simple example:

```
HANDLE hndl=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD pos={0,0};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hndl, pos);
```

But why are you running your timer in a separate thread? There shouldn't be any need to do that. Just measure the time elapsed from the start of the game (see examples here: [How to use clock() in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220477/how-to-use-clock-in-c)), and then subtract the elapsed time from the total time limit.

Comment: I *think* that SetConsoleCursorPosition is global, so using it in a thread could interfere with the output from the main thread.  WriteConsoleOutput might be a better choice.